# Deleting a lot of keys in Redis

Tags: bash, redis, xargs

Trying to do something like:

```
# redis-cli keys "resque:lock:*" |xargs -0 redis-cli del
xargs: argument line too long
```

What's the best way to work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the `-0`. I'm not familiar with redis, but from what I can tell `redis-cli keys` doesn't use a NUL separator.

The reason it barfs without it is because of the way it handles quotes. From `man xargs`:

> **xargs** reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (**which can be protected  with  double or  single  quotes  or  a backslash**) or newlines, and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard input.  Blank lines on the standard input are ignored.

Try `xargs -d '\n'`. That'll disable xarg's "smart" quote-handling and tell it to just read arguments line by line.

Comment: If I do that, I get this output from xargs: xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: @randombits: Note, though, that [`del`](http://redis.io/commands/del) is variadic since 2.6 -- i.e., it takes an arbitrary number of arguments. So you could do something like `redis-cli del $(redis-cli keys "resque:lock:*")`.

Comment: I don't know if you could be interested but you may want to use Redsmin ( https://redsmin.com ) a GUI for Redis that supports batch operations (deletion/rename/...) on keys that match a pattern.